Creating a dynamic function
Good day.
Please advise, I'm a complete newbie in pG.
I have this idea
There are system tables that store metadata.
SELECT DISTINCT
cast(table_name as text)as   table_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name=t_name
The idea is that the function input is the table name, and at the output I want to count the number of rows in this table and also display it on the screen.
I don't understand how I can get the number of rows from the table itself, having only metadata
I'm trying to use the function EXECUTE format( $$SELECT count(*) FROM %I;$$, tableoid ) INTO _cnt_var; but don;t understand how
